# Display function of Binary Tree is not working properly

Tags: c++, recursion, display

I created a program for a binary tree. Due to some reason, I am not able to display it properly. Please help me to write it up in the proper format. Here is the code and please let me know if there are some other errors.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node *left, *right;
    node(int x)
    {
        data = x;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
};
class tree
{
public:
    node *p;    
    node *create()
    {
        int x;
        cout << "Enter data(-1 for NULL): ";
        cin >> x;
        if(x == -1)
            return NULL;
        p = new node(x);
        cout << "Enter left child: ";
        p -> left = create();
        cout << "Enter right child: ";
        p -> right = create();
        return p;
    }
    void display1()
    {
        display(p);
    }
    void display(node *root)
    {
        if(root != NULL)
        {
            display(root -> left);
            cout << " " << root -> data << " ";
            display(root -> right);
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    tree t;
    t.create();
    t.display1();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please describe your problem in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies in your `create()` member function. More specifically, the line `p = new node(x);` is the problem because `p` is a data member and supposed to point to the root of the tree but you're assigning it to new node at every recursive call and thus effectively losing the nodes at previous recursive calls. This leads to wrong/unexpected output when you call `display` function because `p` is not pointing to the root of the tree.

Correct implementation

```cpp
node *create(){
    int x;
    cout << "Enter data(-1 for NULL): ";
    cin >> x;
    if(x == -1)
        return NULL;
    node* new_node = new node(x); // Create new node
    cout << "Enter left child: ";
    new_node -> left = create(); // Assign left child
    cout << "Enter right child: ";
    new_node -> right = create(); // Assign right child
    p = new_node; // Assign root of tree to p
    return new_node;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know abt it. Could you also help me out with...  how to ask the user if needs to assign the value to the left child or right...

Comment: You can take a `choice` variable as input. Now, `if(choice=='L') new_node -> left = create(); else  new_node -> right = create();`.